# Adobe CQ 5. Retrieve SlingHttpServletRequest inside JAX-RS Resource

Tags: java, jax-rs, aem

Is there any way to get the `SlingHttpServletRequest` instance inside method of the JAX-RS Resource class, e.g. :

```
     @POST
     public Response signUp(@Context SlingHttpServletRequest request) {
         ...
     }
```

I am using Adobe CQ 5.5.

Comment: I don't think so, as a JAX-RS servlet will usually run outside of the Sling request processing cycle. But it depends which JAX-RS library you're using, and how it is "wired" into Sling.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Wink, but I assume it uses a dispatcher Servlet - if that's registered directly with the OSGi HttpService, you won't get a SlingHttpRequest. If on the other hand a Filter is used for dispatching it might be possible to provide a SlingHttpRequest. You could tell by setting a breakpoint on the SlingMainServlet (or observing its log messages) to check if it's involved in the request processing, as that's where the SlingHttpServletRequest is created (more precisely in the RequestData class).

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to figure it out.